# Why does my count command in mysql return wrong value -1?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-sql, sqlcommand

I'm using gcloud mysql and inserting values and stuff using c#.
Im trying to get amount of records in table Categories_tbl. My code is:
but after executing x is equal to -1 which wrong. what could it be?

```
MySqlCommand count_categories = new MySqlCommand(
  "SELECT COUNT(CategoryId) FROM Categories_tbl;", 
   connection);

x = count_categories.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: `x=count_categories.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: thank you! another question- if i want to get the values from SELECT * G=FROM Categories_tbl; as List<Category>- hoe could i do that?

Comment: In this case you should use `count_categories.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: i did, this is my code:
                MySqlCommand select_all_categories = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Categories_tbl", connection);
                using (var reader = select_all_categories.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                        return (List<COMCategory>)reader[0]; // if you want int as a result
                }
but i get error that cannot convert from string to list.

Comment: you have to use `while`, not `for`, create each `Category` instance and put it into the list (see my answer)

Comment: ok. i did. but again- the error. i think that reader[0] is string. why and how can i cahnge it?

Comment: please, have a look at my answer - `Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]),` - use `Convert` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

```
count_categories.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

returns how many records *are affected*; you don't call `insert`, `update`, `delete` so you have `-1`. Put instead

```
x = count_categories.ExecuteScalar();
```

which execute the query and return single result. Another (more wordy) possibility

```
using (var reader = count_categories.ExecuteReader()) {
  if (reader.Read())
    x = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]); // if you want int as a result
  else {
    // cursor is empty
  }
}
```

**Edit:** which can be used if you want to read *several* records, e.g.

```
List<Category> list = new List<Category>(); 

using (var reader = count_categories.ExecuteReader()) {
  while (reader.Read()) {
    //TODO: put the right syntax here
    Category category = new Category() {
      Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]),
    };  

    list.Add(category);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "NonQuery", this **is** a query and you want the result:

```
x = count_categories.ExecuteScalar();
```

Since I don't know what type your `x` is, you may need to cast it to the proper type.